# Is there any function in mongodb which performs like decode in oracle?

Tags: mongodb, spring-data-mongodb

```
 <bean id="update" class="java.lang.String">
        <constructor-arg value="update deployment set
        status = decode(status,'CANCELED',status,'PAUSED',status,:status)
        ,end_ts =:endTimeStamp
        ,last_update_time = :now
        where deployment_id = :deploymentId"/>
    </bean>
```

This function does the inline column updation. I want to acheive similarly in spring-data-mongodb

Comment: See https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/switch/